# ReactJS , Get data from Firebase order issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Get data from the firebase it's fine but when I send data I want that the last data is after the last item of the array but I don't know what is the default order but the order is not as I want like:

[a,b,bc] its data get from firebase when I send **c** and **d** its look like

[c,a,b,bc] or [c,a,d,b,bc] like what is the default order i did't understand

i want like:

[a,b,bc,c] or [a,b,bc,c,d]

**Get data from firebase**

```
 db.collection("messages").onSnapshot((snap) => {
      let messages = [];
      snap.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        messages.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
      });
      console.log(messages);
      setmessge(messages);
    });
```

**Send data into firebase**

```
 const dataInput = {
      date_time: new Date().toLocaleString(),
      message,
      sender_id: userId,
    };
    db.collection("messages").add(dataInput);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase documentation states clearly how the matching query documents are returned based on their `ID` ascending order:

> By default, a query retrieves all documents that satisfy the query in
> ascending order by document ID.

You can specify an `orderBy` criteria on your collection references when retrieving data to get it sorted per the criteria:

```
db.collection("messages")
  .orderBy("date_time")
  .onSnapshot((snap) => {
    // ...   
});
```